# Wright-Fisher Simulation of Genetic Drift using R

Tags: r, simulation

I'm trying to run a simulation of the [wright-fisher model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_drift#Wright.E2.80.93Fisher_model) of genetic drift in R.

```
# Wright-Fisher simulation
# n = number of individuals
# f = number of focal alleles at base population
n=10
f=1
pop = as.matrix( c( rep(0,n-f), rep(1,f) ) )
pop = as.matrix( sample(pop, n, replace=T) )
```

This works, effectively this is one replicate, and each time I run the final line of script is a new generation. What I would like to do, but can't, is **have a loop which automatically loops it for X generations and repeat for Y number of replicates**.

It should **store the results for each generation in a dataframe and then allow me to plot them in a graph** which looks something like this (where f/n is allele frequency, each replicate is represented by one line, and the number of generations determines the length of the X axis)...
[image]

Comment: There has been a close vote because "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center." Could you explain why you think so (so I can tailor the question to suit better)? As far as I'm concerned it is a specific programming problem.

Comment: It's probably because you have an idea of your desired output, but haven't demonstrated enough of the necessary leg-work that is typically require of a SO question.

Comment: To assume that is wrong, I tried a huge number of things and spent a lot of time reading yesterday but couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Pop   = Replicate populations
# Gen   = Generations
# NM    = Male population size
# NF    = Female population size
# P     = Frequency of focal allele

GenDriftSim = function(Pop = Pop, Gen = Gen, NM, NF, P, graph = "y", histo = "y"){
            P = (2*(NM+NF))*P
            NE = round((4*NM*NF)/(NM+NF),0)
            SR = round(NM/NF,2)
            Na = NM+NF
            if(graph=="y"){
            plot(c(0,0),type = "n", main = bquote('N'[M]~'/ N'[F]~'='~.(SR)*', N'[A]~'='~.(Na)*', N'[E]~'='~.(NE)), cex.main = 1, 
                xlim = c(1,Gen), ylim=c(0,1), xlab = "Generations", ylab = "Fequency of focal allele")
            }else{}
            for (i in 1:Pop){
            N = NM+NF
            startA = as.vector(c(rep(1, times = P),rep(0, times = (2*N)-P)))
            Population = matrix(c(
                c(sample(startA, size = 2*N, replace = FALSE)),
                c(rep("M", times = NM), rep("F", times = NF))),
                ncol = 3)
            SimResults[(Gen*i)+1-Gen, 3] <<- sum(as.numeric(Population[,1:2]))/(N*2)
            for(j in 1:(Gen-1)){

                    Population = matrix(c(
                        c(sample(sample(Population[(1:NM),1:2], replace = TRUE),N, replace = TRUE)),
                        c(sample(sample(Population[(1+NM):N,1:2], replace = TRUE),N, replace = TRUE)),
                        c(rep("M", times = NM), rep("F", times = NF))), ncol = 3)
                    SimResults[(Gen*i)+1+j-Gen, 3] <<- sum(as.numeric(Population[,1:2]))/(N*2)
                    }
                s = (i*Gen)-Gen+1; e = i*Gen
                r = as.vector(SimResults[s:e, 3])
                if(graph=="y"){
                points(r~c(1:Gen), type = "l")
                }else{}
            }
            if(histo == "y"){SimResults[,1] = rep(1:Pop, each = Gen)
            SimResults[,2] = rep(1:Gen, times = Pop)
            hist(SimResults[,3][SimResults[,2]==Gen], breaks = 100, cex.lab = 0.7, cex.axis = 0.7, xlim = c(0,1), cex.main = 1, main = bquote('N'[M]~'/ N'[F]~'='~.(SR)*', N'[A]~'='~.(Na)*', N'[E]~'='~.(NE)), xlab = paste0("Frequency of focal allele after ",Gen," Generations"))
            }else{}
}

Pop = 10
Gen = 25
P = 0.5

SimResults = matrix(data = NA, ncol = 3, nrow = Gen*Pop)
GenDriftSim(Pop = Pop, Gen = Gen, NM = 100, NF = 900, P = P, graph = "y",  histo = "n")
GenDriftSim(Pop = Pop, Gen = Gen, NM = 180, NF = 180, P = P, graph = "y",  histo = "n")
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function I wrote a few years ago.  You can set the pop size, generations to simulate for, and replicates.

Since you haven't shown any code of your own, I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to store output.  At any rate, this should get you going:

```
Drift_graph = function(t,R){
  N<-250
  p<-0.5
  freq<-as.numeric();
    for( i in 1:t ){
      A1=rbinom(1,2*N,p)
      p=A1/(N*2);
      freq[length(freq)+1]<-p;
    }
  plot(freq,type="l",ylim=c(0,1),col=3,xlab="t",ylab=expression(p(A[1])))
    for(u in 1:R){
      freq1<-as.numeric();
      p<-0.5
        for( j in 1:t ){
          A1=rbinom(1,2*N,p)
          p=A1/(N*2);
          freq1[length(freq1)+1]<-p;
        }
      random<-sample(1:1000,1,replace=F)
      randomcolor<-colors()[random] 
      lines(freq1,type="l",col=(randomcolor))
    }
}

Drift_graph(2000,50)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't get the results in to a dataframe which is why I didn't click accept, but I have up voted it. I eventually found a simulator online and have modified (and annotated) that to my needs. Thanks.